# How to exclude user defined field on Contex.InsertOnSubmit() in LINQ-To-SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have table ***CustomerPurchase*** and equivalent data class DBML file also created. In this, DBML class, I have added my Custom field '***TotalAmount***' for calculations to show in the Listivew. but InsertOnSubmit(), it is throwing an error as Invalid column name '***TotalAmount***'.

How can I exclude this user defined field while submit?

Comment: Is this field calculated?

Comment: Yes it is. Summation of other few fields. i.e Qty * MRP + service tax + other taxes so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside the `dbml` file, you can see it is generate `partial classes`, so you can some partial classes to your entities, and create other properties, like `TotalAmount` you need. There you can access other properties and make calculated property, for sample:

```
namespace YourEntityNameSpace
{
    public partial class CustomerPurchase 
    {
        public double TotalAmount
        { 
            get
            {
                // your code goes here to calculate, for sample:
                return UnitPrice * Amount;
            }
        }
    }
}
```